# Run time page designer in ASP mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How would one go about to have a page / layout designer on run time, and save the layout(that then later on would be rendered with retrieved data).

The scenario :
I have a host application/website, where a user can upload his dll and view as a plugin/widget.
now i want the user to have a graphical designer where he can see all existing plugins or widgets. This is where he can drag and drop the plugins on the page where he would like them, allowing him to also re-size the plugin as he requires it as well.

one of the closest I could find to the type of behavior that i find closest would be. [Dock Spawn](http://www.dockspawn.com/) (Mabey this would still work ?)

what would the best way be to implement such a solution, allowing an admin portal where the user can edit his page. as well as saving this page and allow it to load on another portal.

using existing CMS would not be an option, and any third party tools would be considered

Thank you!

EDIT

I have decided to go with Jason's answer. Implementing JQueryUI's Drag-able, re-sizing. then saving the X and Y co-ordinates for reloading at the same position.

Will still find a solution for the re-sizing(maybe some math...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately what you need to do is wrapper the widgets in `<div>` elements and save [the position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) e.g. left, top, width, height. That way, you can move the position of the `<div>` containing a widget to the specific left, top based on what is stored in any config for that widget.

I don't believeyou need a thrid party library for this, as long as you're happy understanding about positioning in CSS, you should be able to do this yourself.

EDIT:

In resposne to your comments:
You can save the data however you like - serialize it to a file, store in the cloud, save to a local database. It's totally up to you based on your needs.

Regards how the widgets will be positioned based on the device you are looking at, that's where things get tricky. ou will simply have to test that yourself, by trying out a simple widget, positioning it using top, left, etc and see what it looks like on, say, desktop mobile and tablet.

You will likely have to change the `position` CSS style in order to correctly position the `<div>`. My CSS is a bit hazy to be honest, so I can't say with authority which `position` value you will need. Hopefully this will be enough to get you up and running though.

Comment: First, Thanks for the input :)
Would i save it via serialization ?
if I take this approach, would the div elements still re-size according to screen size ?
I.E: I build the view on my 1920*1080 monitor, and now open it on my phone. my best guess would be it would load those saved pixel sizes. or am I going to be surprised ? (ps. I'm a WPF dev moving over to mvc.)

Comment: Thank you Jason, I will use your approach, please see my edit for more information on how I plan to do it. Marked as answer.